# Elasticsearch - Where to place unicast_hosts.txt file for cluster setup in Elasticsearch 6.5?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch  Cluster Setup doubt:
Where to place `unicast_hosts.txt` file for cluster setup in ES 6.5?

In elasticsearch website (6.5) it is mentioned to put the `unicast_hosts.txt` file in below directory:

```
$ES_PATH_CONF/discovery-file/unicast_hosts.txt
```

I have installed ES 6.5

```
[root@xxxx discovery-file]# pwd

/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/discovery-file

[root@xxxx discovery-file]# ls -ltr

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1503 May 20 16:21 plugin-descriptor.properties

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 152 May 20 16:21 NOTICE.txt

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 6368 May 20 16:21 discovery-file-6.5.4.jar

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 11358 May 20 16:21 LICENSE.txt
```

Now do I need to put the `unicast_hosts.txt` inside `discovery-file-6.5.4.jar` or just in this directory.

Please suggest!

Comment: it depends on the kind of install you've made? RPM, Debian, tarball?

Comment: It's RPM installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I provided on [discuss](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/where-to-place-unicast-hosts-txt-file-for-cluster-setup-in-es-6-5/181799/2?u=dadoonet):

It should be in the elasticsearch config dir. The same directory as you have `elasticsearch.yml`.

So if your config dir is: `/foo`, then place this file under `/foo/discovery-file/unicast_hosts.txt`.

Depending on how you installed elasticsearch, it might be in `/etc/elasticsearch/discovery-file/unicast_hosts.txt`.

Note that you need to also add the following to your `elasticsearch.yml` file:

```
discovery.zen.hosts_provider: file
```